# Meaning of も in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-も

I came across the following sentence:

> どうしても納豆だけは食べられない。

The sentence as a whole makes sense, but what meaning or function does も have here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`〜ても` means "Even if X". In this case, "No matter what I do, Natto I cannot eat."

> 雨が降っても強行だ
>   走っても間に合わない
>   見つかったとしても壊れているに違いない
>   食べてもよい

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify, this is used with て-form right?

Comment: @mamemaki: Yes, it can also be で like 子供でも知っている.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the definition of [`どうしても`](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/155913/m0u/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82/):

> どう努力【どりょく】してみても。

That is to say `regardless of how hard (I) try`. `も` here means `regardless`. It's part of a general pattern of `~(て/で)も`, which has a general meaning of `even if`.